# What is the better(neater) way to find the largest list range in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the dict which consists of lists as values. List is `len(2)` representing the range of an array:

`new_dict = {0: [0, 7], 1:[15, 21], 2:[-5, 3]}`

I need to find the key with list that has the largest range i.e. largest `list[1] - list[0]`

I've done it this way and it works fine, but I am assuming it can be done in simpler, or more pythonic way.

```
largest = float("-inf")
largest_list = []
for key in new_dict.keys():
        temp = new_dict[key][1] - new_dict[key][0]
        if temp > largest:
            largest = temp
            largest_list = new_dict[key]
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That finds the largest value difference, but the question was to find the corresponding key.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah, I had assumed his code did what he wanted because it was preceded by "I've done it this way and it works fine, but I am assuming it can be done in simpler, or more pythonic way." But now I see the rest of the question asks for a key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a custom `key` function:

```py
>>> new_dict = {0: [0, 7], 1:[15, 21], 2:[-5, 3]}
>>> max(new_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1] - x[1][0])[0]
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a little fun...

```
>>> import operator
>>> min(new_dict, key=lambda k: operator.sub(*new_dict[k]))
2
```

or

```
>>> max(new_dict, key=lambda k: len(range(*new_dict[k])))
2
```

or

```
>>> min(new_dict, key=lambda k: int.__sub__(*new_dict[k]))
2
```